# Combining Woocommerce with ios in app purchase

Tags: ios, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to sync ios in app purchase with woocommerce purchase(web). So when user purchases something in apple store(product lists are same on both side) i would like to view it in woocommerce that item was purchased by that user. FYI, I have a json api plugin that i am using to make request between ios app and site. Any idea how i can do this?

Comment: Can't you just fake out the transaction going through woocommerce?

Comment: I was thinking of it but not sure exactly where woocommerce start their transaction (or action they use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i resolved it

```
global $woocommerce;
$user = get_user_by('id',$shopId);
 if ($user){
    wp_set_current_user($shopId,$user->user_login);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($shopId);
        do_action('wp_login',$user->user_login);
    }

    if (is_user_logged_in()){
        $cart = new WC_Cart();
        $checkout = new WC_Checkout();
        if ($cart->add_to_cart($productId)){
            $orderId = $checkout->create_order(intval($shopId));



        }
        if (!empty($orderId)){
            $order = new WC_Order($orderId);
            if (!empty($order)){
                $order->update_status("completed","ios app purchase");//I HAD TO SET IT TO COMPLETE SINCE USER BOUGHT IT FROM IOS IN APP PURCHASE
            }
            //

        }
        else{
            $order = array('fail');
        }
    }
    else{
        $order = array();
    }

    return array($order);
```