# Connecting WooCommerce and stores in-app purchases

Tags: woocommerce, google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm looking for a way of connecting WooCommerce and both in-app Play Store & App Store purchases.

Just like [in this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25731405/combining-woocommerce-with-ios-in-app-purchase), I would like the products purchased in the stores to appear on WooCommerce. The person in the topic linked seems to have found a way, but I do not get where they put their code.
I have no idea wether it's a good practice or a bad one (I guess that not finding any documentation out there indicates mostly the second choice...), or even if there really is a way, but I'm curious.
Do you have any ideas on how to do this, or if it's even possible?
Thank you, and don't hesitate if you need more information!